# How to change the color of the checked/toggled button programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let say I've a toggle button which is checked initially and the background color (the color when the button is checked/toggled, NOT the color of the button itself) is blue by default. How to change the background color of the checked/toggled button?

For example:

```
if (myCondition == true)
    myToggleBtn.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```

The code above is just change the color of the toggle button itself, but I want to change the color checked/toggled button.

**Updated**

```html
<ToggleButton x:Name="Line1Btn" Content="Line 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,84,0,0"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="11" Height="26" Width="50"
              IsEnabled="True" BorderBrush="#FFC7C7C7" Click="Line1Btn_Click">
  <ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Setter Property="Background"> 
        <Setter.Value> 
          <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFCFCFCF" Offset="0"/> 
            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/> 
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers> 
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True"> 
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSeaGreen"/> 
        </Trigger> </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

**Updated 2**

[image]

Generated from the same code, but show different results.

Comment: You'd need an event handler that can change the color when the button is clicked. But, this isn't really the WPF way to do things. The right way to do it would be using styles that will change when the button is toggled.

Comment: This should be done in WPF with triggers and property setters, not in code. Just as @MattBurland said.

Comment: apply trigger in style of button.

Answer (score 2):

[image]You can use this style for the button

> ```
>                <Style TargetType="Button">
>                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
>                 <Style.Triggers>
>                     <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
>                         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> 
>                     </Trigger>
>                 </Style.Triggers>
>             </Style>
> ```

Comment: That was real quick!! ;)

Comment: Hi @Nakul Chaudhary, I've tried with your solution, it works for Foreground color, but when I changed it to Background, it has no effect, still give me the window blue color when the toggle button is checked.

Comment: Hi @YWah, I tested with Background color it is working fine.  <ToggleButton Margin="100" Content="Click">
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>

Comment: Hi @YWah, Please ensure not background color is set locally.

Comment: Hi @Nakul Chaudhary, it still the same, even I tried in a clean code the result still the same. By the way, is it caused by the .net  framework target version? I'm using ver4.5...

Comment: @YWah, I is working fine at my end.It will not depend on .net framework.Can you share your code.

Comment: @YWah,I checked code it is working fine except i dont known what you written in event "Line1Btn_Click". On clicking button background color changed to dark green and border remain same. You can see changed button in the answer.

Comment: @Nakul Chaudhary, I created a new wpf window and just add that part of code without any clicking function, the result still the same. May I know what version of visual studio did you used? I'm using 2013 ultimate

Comment: Hi @Nakul Chaudhary, the reason why it worked for you but not me is because the windows theme. I referred to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b90b7338-f163-4fcc-ad49-b93087b2eb0b/why-the-background-of-toggle-button-cannot-be-changed-in-the-style-trigger-of-ischecked?forum=wpf). You can see the results above.