# Changing text and Backgroud color on toggle button WPF

Tags: wpf, toggle

I'm connecting and disconnecting an internet connection on the click of a `Toggle Button`. The default values of the button should be:
`Content= Connect`, `Background=blue`.

On click, after the connection is established, it should change to `Content= Disconnect`, `Background=red`.

The text changes, but the color doesn't, until unchecked is pressed. Help?

XAML

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggle", Content="Connect", Background="Blue", Checked="Check_btn", Unchecked="Uncheck_btn"/>
```

Code Behind

```
private void Check_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
  //Code for connection
   .....
   toggle.Content = "Disconnect";
   toggle.Background = Brushes.Red;
}

private void Uncheck_btn(object sender, RoutedEventArg e)
{
  //Code for disconnection
   .....
   toggle.Content = "Connect";
   toggle.Background = Brushes.Blue;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of the checked/toggled button programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989603/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-checked-toggled-button-programatically)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this did not have an accepted answer

Comment: You are missing an ' " ' on the unchecked case and you have a space to much. You also need x:Name and not Name. Try setting the Properties correctly and check if you hit your methods

Comment: @Brezelmann Thank you for pointing out, but I couldn't copy the code from my work space, so these errors were not in the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ToggleButton Name="toggle" Content="Connect" Background="Blue" Checked="Check_btn" Unchecked= "Uncheck_btn">
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>-->
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

The background is harcoded in the default one.

Comment: But this would just change the default values, not the ones when the checked events would be fired, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "default values"? This will change the background of the `ToggleButton` according to your requirements. Did you try it?